# What is the equivalent API of oracle RAWTOHEX/HEXTORAW in SPARK/SCALA?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to insert into oracle database table, with one of the column type as RAW(16). I am looking for a dataframe api which can do the equivalent of oracle RAWTOHEX/HEXTORAW.

Comment: If I understand, you have an hex string you want to convert to oracle raw type. According to http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/RAW provided examples, it seems you can insert hex string as raw directly without converting it. Did you try to insert this hex string directly ? If so, what was the output ?

Comment: @Vincet Doba it worked. 

hex(expr) - Converts expr to hexadecimal.

Examples:

> SELECT hex(17);
 11
> SELECT hex('Spark SQL');
 537061726B2053514C